# Regex match a sequence of numbers and a character . between them

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need to get all `${{1.33.98}}` strings from a string.

`new RegExp('\\$\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}', 'g');` doesnt work well on case like:

`${{1.33.98}${{2.44.1}}` - should match only `${{2.44.1}}` because `${{1.33.98}` is missing `}` at this example.

So it shouldn't match if string missing any of the two `{{` or two `}}` or `$`.

Between `{{` and `}}` can be only a sequence of numbers separated by a dot - ex. `4.23.4545`

Thanks

Comment: Replace `.*?` with `[^{}]+`, or even `\d[\d.]*` since you need only numbers.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be working, though will do more tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match unwelcome values because `.` can match any char, and thus it matches any chars from the leftmost `{{` to the first `}}` to the right of `{{`.

You may use

```
/\${{(\d[\d.]*)}}/g
```

Or, if the dot-separated number format is important

```
/\${{(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)}}/g
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aw6auj/1/) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aw6auj/2).

Note that if the strings are prevalidated, and you are sure there are no `{` and `}` inside `${{` and `}}`, you may even use `[^{}]*` instead of `\d[\d.]*`:

```
/\${{([^{}]*)}}/g
```

So, you either capture

- `\d[\d.]*`   -  a digit and then 0 or more digits and dots

  or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` - 1+ digits and then 0+ repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits.

JS demo:

```js
const s = '${{1.33.98}${{2.44.1}} ${{1.24.52.44.1}}';
let m = [...s.matchAll(/\${{(\d[\d.]*)}}/g)];
console.log(Array.from(m, x => x[1]));
```

For legacy ES versions:

```js
var s = '${{1.33.98}${{2.44.1}} ${{1.24.52.44.1}}';
var rx = /\${{(\d[\d.]*)}}/g, results = [], m;
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Sorry for this question, but how do you set `/\${{(\d[\d.]*)}}/g`  to `new RegExp()` ? :)

Comment: You do not need it. Use it as is. It is a regex literal.